# Properly bundling DLLs with C programs

Tags: c, windows, dll, bundle

I've been trying to bundle a few DLL libraries with my C program. I can paste the DLLs that I need in the directory of the executable, and it works fine.

I need to organise the files inside my executable folder in other folders. **My problem is that whenever I move the DLL files to another folder (inside the executable directory), the executable fails to find those DLL files.**

According to this photo:

[image]

I don't want to add a new value to the environment path, and I don't want to touch other folders outside of my executable directory. **Is there a way to tell my executable to look for DLL files in a folder in my executable directory?** Can I change the name of the DLLs folder to another name so the executable can access these files? Please help me!

**Edit:** I've tried changing the "*current directory*" by using the `chdir()` function. My approach didn't work, any idea why is that?

```c
#include <unistd.h> //Used for chdir()

int Start(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    chdir("/bin/"); //change the "current directory" to "bin/"

    return Start(argc, argv);

}

#include "./program.c" //Includes the `Start()` function
```

Comment: I do not know specifically, thus only a comment. But logic dictates that the executable needs to know where to find the DLLS. If they are not at someplace the environment (e.g. Windows) already checks, and they are not at the place the executable knows about (i.e. the executable dir `./`), then the remaining option is to hard code the paths in the executable (if even possible), which does not seem like a great idea.

Comment: What's wrong with just having the DLLs in the same directory as the executable? That's how it is done usually.

Comment: @Jabberwock, I just want the files to be more organised.

Comment: @EnderAdel this is pretty useless, nowadays programs are started via the start menu or via some link, or via a command line. Nobody should browse to the directory where the executable is and double click on the executable.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I know. The problem is that the program in question is not gonna be mine, I need all the files in this "*program template*" to be easy to understand and organised.

Comment: @EnderAdel I'm afraid you need to use option 4 of the Robert's answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you want to package your application with an executable file and several DLL files. You have several options in front of you.

1. Don’t do that, this don’t give a lot of added value
2. Quick & dirty: you could put the executable and the DLLs files into the same directory and add a BAT file which change the `%PATH%` with `set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\dlls` and then start your program
3. You could manually load the DLLs files with `LoadLibrary` from the directory you want, this bring additional work because you need to retrieve all the functions from your DLLs one by one and store them into pointers (pointer to function, this is the approach from `SDL` library, you can see the link below)
4. Last option, you could put your executable in the same directory as your `DLL` and write an additional program, let’s call it a `starter` or `loader` which task is only to start the good executable file. This would be my preferred approach.

Reference:

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/c59d4dcd38c382a1e9b69b053756f1139a861574/src/core/windows/SDL_xinput.c

Comment: I didn't get option 4, isn't this what he's describing in the first sentence of the question? And what's the point of the starter/loader then?

Comment: The point of the loader is that you don't need to deal with DLL location as they will be in the same directory as your main program. So you have no code to change on your current program. You just write a very small `starter` which start the main program located in the subdirectory with the `DLLs` (basically with `GetModuleFilename` & `CreateProcess`)

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: You can have a directory with "my-program.exe" and a subdirectory "dlls". This looks clean in some way, the user is not confused as there are only 2 elements, he just click on the "my-program.exe" to start the program. Under the hood, the "my-program.exe" just executes the "dlls\program.exe".

Comment: Loading the libraries using "LoadLibrary" is not possible, since the included files are used by the built-in C libraries. As for the 4th option, I've been trying to do that for the past hour, but it's not working.

Comment: The option 4 is definitively working, I used that for several years. The program itself is straightforward. You need to calculate the full filename of your real program (basically get the executable directory with `GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH)`, then you remove the last part `my-program.exe`, you concatenate with `subdir\my-program.exe` and start this with let's say `ShellExecute`)

Comment: But the option 1) is a really reasonable option in my opinion.

Comment: I guess I'm gonna have to do option #4 for now.